# HttpURLConnection (Connection not established)

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

```
try{
    String a="http://10.0.2.2/test2.php";
    Log.d("URL",a);
    url = new URL(a);
    Log.d("URL23",a);

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    Log.d("URL3",a);

    try {
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        // just want to do an HTTP GET here
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        // give it 15 seconds to respond
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(35 * 1000);
        urlConnection.connect();

        int status = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        switch (status) {
            case 200:Log.d("CASE","@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@       200");
            case 201:
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                br.close();
                Log.d("CASE 201 String",sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

It is throwing an exception at `getResponseCode` and also at `urlConnection.getInputStream()` (if switch case not used). Can anyone please tell why i am not able to set up connection using `HttpURLConnection` and error in my code.

Comment: did you specify the internet permission in manifest.?

Comment: Yes, i have added the permission

Comment: using emulator or from device because you are accessing a local url ?

Comment: using device through usb debugging

Comment: just try to open that url in web browser it must open there. since it is a local url so both the server and your device must be in same network

Comment: are you trying that thing in Thread or AsyncTask right??

Comment: @Aiyaz Yes, in AsyncTask

Comment: @GopalSinghSirvi url opens in web browser only if i replace 10.0.2.2 by localhost

Comment: do i need to replace 10.0.2.2 by ipv4 of my pc even for usb debugging?

Comment: if the url is not accessible then how can you make a call to that url in application?

Comment: make that website accessible in LAN Network and connect your own device to same network with either wifi or also you can use reverse tethering to get internet from your developer PC

Comment: please can you show us your stack trace.

Comment: @GopalSinghSirvi Thanku soo much...It worked.

Comment: welcome @user2796222 can you please accept the answer it will help another having same issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your local website is not accessible through your device.
Find the issue or make it runnable on your device then try again the same procedure it will work.
If you use local website with the android programming the local website must be accessible via the device which is used for testing. So configure the site properly on LAN Network and connect your device on same network.