# Why when sending http request from java to pc server it does nothing?

Tags: java, c#, android

On the pc in the constructor i did:

```
WebServer ws = new WebServer(SendResponse, "http://localhost:8080/");
ws.Run();
```

And the WebServer class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace Manager
{
    class WebServer
    {
        private readonly HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
        private readonly Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> _responderMethod;

        public WebServer(string[] prefixes, Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method)
        {
            if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
                throw new NotSupportedException(
                    "Needs Windows XP SP2, Server 2003 or later.");

            // URI prefixes are required, for example 
            // "http://localhost:8080/index/".
            if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");

            // A responder method is required
            if (method == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("method");

            foreach (string s in prefixes)
                _listener.Prefixes.Add(s);

            _responderMethod = method;
            _listener.Start();
        }

        public WebServer(Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method, params string[] prefixes)
            : this(prefixes, method) { }

        public void Run()
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Webserver running...");
                try
                {
                    while (_listener.IsListening)
                    {
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((c) =>
                        {
                            var ctx = c as HttpListenerContext;
                            try
                            {
                                string rstr = _responderMethod(ctx.Request);
                                byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
                                ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
                                ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                            }
                            catch { } // suppress any exceptions
                            finally
                            {
                                // always close the stream
                                ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                            }
                        }, _listener.GetContext());
                    }
                }
                catch { } // suppress any exceptions
            });
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _listener.Stop();
            _listener.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And in the android studio i'm sending :

```
package com.dan.webservertest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Context;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Locale;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.io.*;

//import com.adilipman.webservertest.DebugServer;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
    public static MainActivity currentActivity;
    TextToSpeech mTts;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(new SingleTouchEventView(this, null));

        currentActivity = this;

        initTTS();
        excutePost("http://10.0.0.3:8080/", "hello world");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Dispatch onStart() to all fragments.  Ensure any created loaders are
     * now started.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        TextToSpeechServer.main(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // call server.stop from here somehow.. ok?ok
    }

    public void initTTS() {
        Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
        checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
            if(resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                mTts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new OnInitListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onInit(int i) {

                        if(i == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                            int result = mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                            if(result == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE
                                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE) {
                                mTts.setPitch(1);
                                mTts.speak(textforthespeacch, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    public static String textforthespeacch = "";
    public static void TextToSpeak(String text) {
        textforthespeacch = text;
    }

    public class SingleTouchEventView extends View {
        private Paint paint = new Paint();
        private Path path = new Path();
        private Path circlePath = new Path();

        public SingleTouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);

            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
            canvas.drawPath(circlePath, paint);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();

            float lastdownx = 0;
            float lastdowny = 0;

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                    circlePath.addCircle(eventX, eventY, 50, Path.Direction.CW);
                    lastdownx = eventX;
                    lastdowny = eventY;
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // nothing to do
                    circlePath.reset();

                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }

            // Schedules a repaint.
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

    private  String excutePost(String targetURL, String urlParameters) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            //Create connection
            URL url = new URL(targetURL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                    Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            //Send request
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.close();

            //Get Response
            java.io.InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(); // or StringBuffer if not Java 5+
            String line;
            while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            return response.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if(connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the java code i'm doing inside the onCreate:

```
excutePost("http://localhost:8080/", "hello world");
```

But it does nothing.
I first run the server in the pc then run the program in the android studio.

What i want to do is to send a string from the java to the pc and display the string on the pc on form1. For exmaple: hello world

Later i will do that when i touch the android device smartphone screen it will send a command to the pc. But for now it's not working at all the server on the pc and the client on the android.

Comment: access it with ip address of your machine instead of localhost

Comment: I changed now on my pc to http://109.65.70.77/ but now when running the program i'm getting exception access denied on _listener.Start(); in the WebServer class

Comment: see this qustion and all comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595347/httpurlconnection-connection-not-established/30611420